# Will a brush be disposed if created in the call to a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0

below is a fragment of code that is found in my paint method. I am not sure what it is called when I create an object such as the brush this manner, but never the less will it be disposed of properly, or do I need to be concerned about it?

```
g.DrawString("12", _ContentFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(25, 25));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819096/is-it-important-to-dispose-solidbrush-and-pen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't. Try this instead:

```
using ( var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black) )
  g.DrawString("12", _ContentFont, brush, new PointF(25, 25));
```

But when it comes to black, it is even better to just:

```
  g.DrawString("12", _ContentFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(25, 25));
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  It becomes *eligible* for disposal.  There's no guarantee on when that actually happens; it could could hang around for quite some time.

These days I would consider that a bug, though I know of time when I didn't know any better, either.