# Incorrect scaling of Pen when using Graphics.ScaleTransform

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, scaletransform

I'm seeing strange behaviour when drawing a line with a scale transform (`Graphics.ScaleTransform()` - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform.aspx)) in my `OnPaint()` method.

When using a large y-scale factor for the `ScaleTransform` method, then if the x-scale is set above 1x, the line suddenly becomes much larger.

Setting the width of pen with which the line is drawn to -1 seems to get round the problem, but I do not want to draw a very thin line (the line must be printed later, 1px is too thin).

Here's some sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class GraphicsTestForm : Form
{
    private readonly float _lineLength = 300;
    private readonly Pen _whitePen;

    private Label _debugLabel;

    public GraphicsTestForm()
    {
        ClientSize = new Size(300, 300);

        Text = @"GraphicsTest";
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        _debugLabel = new Label
        {
            ForeColor = Color.Yellow,
            BackColor = Color.Transparent
        };
        Controls.Add(_debugLabel);

        _lineLength = ClientSize.Width;
        _whitePen = new Pen(Color.White, 1f); // can change pen width to -1
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        float scaleX = ClientSize.Width / _lineLength;
        const int ScaleY = 100;

        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);

        _debugLabel.Text = @"x-scale: " + scaleX;

        // scale the X-axis so the line exactly fits the graphics area
        // scale the Y-axis by scale factor
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scaleX, ScaleY);

        float y = ClientSize.Height / (ScaleY * 2f);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(_whitePen, 0, y, _lineLength, y);

        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    }
}
```

I would like the line/pen to scale gracefully, without jumping in size so dramatically.

(Additionally, I noticed that when the line is very large, it is not drawn continuously across multiple monitors. Perhaps this is related?)

Comment: Asking GDI+ to do unusual things is never not a problem.  Unusual here meaning to draw with a thickness that varies depending on the angle.  Keep the X- and Y-scaling factors the same to get a better outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the tip! I actually need to draw a sine curve with 100s of points on the X-axis but Y-axis only between -1 and 1. Hence the difference in X and Y scale factors. Should I just scale the points separately before drawing and forget about the graphics transforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the pen width according to the scale:

```
 _whitePen = new Pen(Color.White, 1f / ScaleY); 
 e.Graphics.DrawLine(_whitePen, 0, y, _lineLength, y);
```

Comment: Is there any problem with continually creating a Pen object?

Comment: This sort-of works: however, the line still does not scale up and down smoothly - for example, if I want a thicker line I used (10f / ScaleY) but this brings back the problem.

Comment: Regarding continuos creation, it is convenient to dispose them. Have a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819096/is-it-important-to-dispose-solidbrush-and-pen)   But, in order to avoid unnecessary performance reduction, you can verify if the previous pen is the same as the one you need now (save the last scale value).

Comment: I moved my entire code from scaling/transforming my stuff to "automatic" ScaleTransform / TranslateTransform, and I have the same problem. As I am drawing a diagram/plot, having both axes on the same scale is not possible though. Am I correct in the assumption that I cannot do what I want to do with ScaleTransform then? My lines look horribly messed up because obviously the Pen gets scaled, and it gets scaled differently in x and y dimension :/

Comment: This answer is only half right. The pen needs to be rescaled in both X and Y directions using myPen.ScaleTransform(xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor), where the scale factors are the inverse of whatever scaling was applied to the graphics object.

Answer (score 1):

I just compensated for the overall scaling in the pens line geometry;-

```
m_Pen->SetWidth(1.0f);
m_Pen->ScaleTransform(1.0f / ZoomX, 1.0f / ZoomY);
```